# We're exceeding the posted [google-pagespeed]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request, scope

[google-pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-pagespeed)

294 questions with the best excerpt ever

> deleted as mod-pagespeed should be used instead.

I'm not sure how [mod-pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-pagespeed) relates here. Going to leave that out of this discussion (seems to fall under the "programming tool" category like [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) does). To clear up confusion, the tags in question are referring to a [Google page analysis tool](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) that aids with SEO, not the [Mod Pagespeed Project](https://www.modpagespeed.com/) (web server plugin)

[pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed) seems to be a direct synonym

> A set of tools from Google for applying performance best practices to web pages.

I'm openly wondering if this is on-topic. A lot of the questions are of the SEO variety, with Google basically "clocking" your website in an SEO way. Since we can't really diagnose why your site is slow, or what's optimal for SEO, it seems to be off-topic. So I'm asking for either

1. Burninate [google-pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-pagespeed) and [pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed)
2. Synonym [google-pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-pagespeed) to [pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed) and clean up the tag

Comment: Will [google-pagespeed] measure our burnination speed?

Comment: It's as on-topic as a question asking how to make a page more responsive: you have to demonstrate that your problem is unique to software development first and make sure it's not too broad.

Comment: Didn't find the pitchforks, but I got some scythes

Comment: Worst burninate title I've seen in a long time... isn't Trogdor-y enough.

Comment: I just Googled "google pagespeed", and it seems like a legit [Apache and Nginx module](https://developers.google.com/speed/), so I'd vote to keep this tag, and go with option 2, and there's also the non-existent right now [tag:ngx-pagespeed] to be added into the mix.

Comment: @KenY-N I think you're confusing this with mod-pagespeed (which I already noted was on-topic). The tags in question refer to a [Google site analysis tool](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

Comment: It appears the current tag description is a clearly wrong edit: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18207809/revisions. I'd suggest burninating [tag:pagespeed] either way, as it's rather ambiguous between the Google technology, the Apache mod, and page loading/rendering/JavaScript speed in general.

Answer (score 25):

[pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed) should be burninated regardless of what we do with the others. It's too easy to confuse it between any and all of:

- The [Google tools](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) in question
- [NGinx and Apache modpagespeed modules](https://www.modpagespeed.com/)
- Page download speed
- Browser rendering speed
- JavaScript runtime speed

This will result in too much inconsistent usage, and many questions in these categories are off topic.

If we want to keep tags for the Google tools and the modules, we should keep [google-pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-pagespeed) and [mod-pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-pagespeed).

Comment: Maybe we should create a seperate post for that.

Comment: @chade_ I'm not sure what you're suggesting needs a separate post, but as these three tags are similarly named and confusion between them is likely, it's simpler and more useful to keep all the relevant discussion in one place.

Answer (score -1):

If you sort by votes ([google-pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-pagespeed?sort=votes&pageSize=50) & [pagespeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagespeed?sort=votes&pageSize=50)) you can see that there are at least a few well received questions that are on topic and the tag seems relevant here.

I also would people using page speed would search for terms used by the tool like `above the fold` in combination with `google page speed`

I would place the tag in the following category as for instance [jslint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jslint) which get's a lot of questions regarding reports of output of the tool.

I whatever case I think the tags should be synonyms

Comment: Care to comment about the downvotes? My suggestion is that we do not remove both tags